# How to add a field to the Moya.Response JSON that wasn't in the real payload from the http response

Tags: swift, swift3, rx-swift, objectmapper, moya

If I have:

```
import Moya
import RxSwift
import ObjectMapper
import Moya_ObjectMapper

provider.request(.callApi(id: id))
      .mapObject(Thing.self)
      .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
      .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
```

...

```
struct Thing: Mappable, Equatable {

  var id: String?

  init?(map: Map) {
  }

  mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
  }
```

Making an http api call and getting back json like {"id: "123"} and it's all working great. A new Thing struct is made with the right id. But what if I want to add "flavor" to Thing and hard code {"id: "123", "flavor": "something"}.

i.e. let's just modify the actual http response body and add `"flavor": "something"` before it gets to the .mapObject method. Where is the right place to tap into that?

And it's not just adding it to the mapping func in Thing because "something" is different for each id. Might be flavor: "something1" and then flavor: "something2". I have this value in the same scope as callApi(id: id) so something like:

```
provider.request(.callApi(id: id))
      .addJSON("flavor", flavor)
      .mapObject(Thing.self)
      .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
      .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
```

But `.addJSON` is something I just made up. It doesn't exist. But there must be some simple solution for this?

Comment: ended up making each http call with Alamofire directly and then it was simple. This is all for https://github.com/andrewarrow/boring_company_chat if anyone is curious.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to modify the actual JSON feels dirty and at two low-level.  But I've been there so no judging from me if it works. :)

I'd approach it by creating a special version of the Moya.Response extension methods available from Moya_ObjectMapper.

```
public extension Response {

  /// Maps data received from the signal into an object which implements the Mappable protocol.
  /// If the conversion fails, the signal errors.
    public func mapObject<T: BaseMappable>(_ type: T.Type, context: MapContext? = nil) throws -> T {
        guard let object = Mapper<T>(context: context).map(JSONObject: try mapJSON()) else {
      throw MoyaError.jsonMapping(self)
    }
   return object
  }
```

I'd add a similar method but with an additional parameter closure (T) -> (T).  So it would essentially return the mapped object after doing another map which would add any necessary information you need into it.